# OpenCV2.4.9.jar file

Tags: java, android, opencv, jar

I want to use OpenCV library in my android app. I have downloaded OpenCV 2.4.9 and I have performed all the steps mentioned in the tutorial I followed, error was

> opencv.android....cannot be resolved

When I searched for this I came to know that I should include opencv_library-2.4.9.jar file. But opencv_library-2.4.9.jar was not present in the file I have downloaded. But then, I have added opencv_library-2.4.3.jar to the project and I am not able to find the 2.4.9.jar file. Can anyone help me in solving the problem? [image]

Comment: You have a version of OpenCV for Android that doesn't contain those imports.  Look on SourceForge instead: http://sourceforge.net/projects/opencvlibrary/files/opencv-android/2.4.9/

Comment: Thank you rayryeng. I used that link to download the file and there is no jar file in that.

Comment: The source is there. Import the source into your project instead.